# $('#el').css('position', 'static !important') not working in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a div that I want to 'smart scroll' up and down with a page. It starts off with position, fixed, and I use jQuery to dicide when to change that:

```
$('#el').css('position', 'static !important');
```

Works great in Safari + Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox. Any reason why this would be?

Comment: what if you remove the whitespace before the "!" or even just remove " !important" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need !important when setting the style property of the element. It will already override any css selectors defined by default.

Comment: Well, unless the stylesheet properties have !important defined this is true. http://jsfiddle.net/bXTxe/

Comment: this is not considered as a solution if you need to override another !important property value

Answer (score 1):

You cant set !important like that with jQuery, but with javascript you can do:

```
document.getElementById('el').style.position = "static !important";
```

But that only seems to work in some browsers, namely Webkit, and is probably why your jQuery css also only works in Chrome/Safari, as they probably did some updates to the library.

On previous versions of jQuery, the css() function when containing !important did absolutely nothing as far as I know.

The only cross browser way of doing this with jQuery is with cssText, something like:

```
$('#el').css('cssText', 'position: static !important');
```

But be aware that cssText replaces the entire inline style tag, and all other styles set that way will have to be included in the cssText once again.

A better way of doing this would be with different classes, like so:

css:

```
.static_element {position: static!important;}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#el").addClass('static_element');
```

and since it uses !important it will override any position set on other classes/ID's as long as they are not set with !important as well, then they will follow the usual order of css rules, and the last rule added will stick.

A good rule is to try and avoid using !important at all, unless there is absolutely no other solution available, and in your example using two classes with one set to fixed, and the other to static would work just fine if for some strange reason just setting the position with $.css() without using !important does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this.  Something like this works in WebKit but not in Gecko:

```
document.getElementById("x").style.color = "red !important";
```

Per spec, this should not work.  It's just a bug in WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has problem reading the !important in css if you use the .css method. It can be fixed by used the attr method.

```
$('#el').attr('style', 'position:static !important');
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not a jquery problem it's actually a javascript bug since changing any style property value doesn't reflect 100% to the style.cssText attribute, the only solution i found is to change the style attribute it self:

```
// using jquery
$('#el').attr('style', 'position:static !important');
```

or

```
// using native javascript
document.getElementById('el').setAttribute('style', 'position:static !important');
```

or changing the style.cssText

```
document.getElementById('el').style.cssText = 'position:static !important';
```